# NSUrlRequest itself adding %0 in url

Tags: iphone, base64, nsurlrequest

The `NSURLRequest` is adding `%0` in `request`. I created the string and converted it into base 64 then send to url, but `NSURLRequest` is automatically adding `%0` in it. Below is the code i am using.

This is how converted to `base 64`.

```
 NSData *plainTextData = [totalStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 NSString *base64String = [plainTextData base64EncodedString];
 NSLog(@"encoded url:%@",base64String);
```

When Api called.

```
NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://mabct.co/api/checkin/%@", [code valueForKey:@"code"]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:
                                [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr]];
                                // [urlStr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];

NSString *responseString = [MyEventApi sendRequest:request];

NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *results = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];
NSLog(@"dict in API-------------%@",results);
return results;
```

This is the converted string in to base 64

```
eyJldmVudElkIjoiNDAiLCJzZWF0IjoiMTBfS2FyYW4gU3VraGlqYV8yNC0wNC0yMDEzIDE3OjE3IiwidXNlcklkIjoiMTAifQ==
```

This is what `NSURLRequest` is sending.

```
eyJldmVudElkIjoiNDAiLCJzZWF0IjoiMTBfS2FyYW4gU3VraGlqYV8yNC0wNC0y%0D%0AMDEzIDE3OjE3IiwidXNlcklkIjoiMTAifQ==
```

This is what i am sending in encoding

```
"{"eventId":"47","seat":"10_Karan Makhija_24-04-2013 10:06","userId":"10"}"
```

I am not getting what is wrong, please guide for the above.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I see that `%0D%0A` is being added to your original string. I googled it and found that:

> %0D%0A is the encoded ASCII non-printable characters of ,
>   which on Microsoft platforms is a NewLine So:
>
> 1. Consider if you accidentally could have replaced some HTML by hitting the return key while editing your files.
>
> 2a. Be aware of what
>   encoding your editor uses for saving the files (typically either
>   ASCII, ANSI, or Unicode)
>
> 2b. Your webserver (an IIS6, likely running
>   on a Windows 2003 Server) serves the files as UTF-8 encoded, which is
>   fine - But you may want to verify that it actually reads the files
>   using same encoding as you've used for saving the files.

Here, is the [SOURCE](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/fCXHNophyQc) if you want to check.

### EDIT

Make sure that your webserver and client uses the same encoding (i.e. `NSUTF8StringEncoding` or any other, but same)

Also, IF base 64 encoding is there on web server. Follow [this](http://agerson.net/base64-encode-and-decode-nsstring-cocoa) link, for implementing category for such encoding/decoding. I hope this will help you.

Comment: This is what i am sending in encoding "{"eventId":"47","seat":"10_Karan Makhija_24-04-2013 10:06","userId":"10"}".

Comment: and i have already used [urlStr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding].

Comment: i didn't get what you said in last comment.

Comment: on serevr used base 64 enciding

Comment: This is what server is recieving "{"eventId":"47","seat":"10_Karan Sukhija_24/04/2�=013, "userId":"10"}"

Comment: the name is just another entry that was picked by string from array, so that's no prob and i tried using NSUnicodeStringEncoding it just gives larger encoded string but result is same.

Comment: this is result of NSUnicodeStringEncoding http://mabct.co/api/checkin/eyJldmVudElkIjoiNDAiLCJzZWF0IjoiMTBfS2FyYW4gU3VraGlqYV8yNC0wNC0y%FF%FE%0D%00%FF%FE%0A%00MDEzIDE4OjM4IiwidXNlcklkIjoiMTAifQ==>